# Data not saved in database cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, save, cakephp-2.0

I have an event table with this fields:

[image]

I use this code to insert data in this table :

```
$oneEvent = array(
    'trainer_id' => $event['trainer_id'],
    'formation_id' => $event['formation_id'],
    'title' =>  $event['title'],
    'start' =>  $event['start'][$i],
    'end' =>    $event['end'][$i],
);
$success = $this->Event->save($oneEvent);
$events_id= $this->Event->inserted_ids;
```

when I run this code I get true and ID of insert element (showed using debug)

[image]

but in database i can't see this field never !!!!.
and when I insert data in phpmyadmin when this request `INSERT INTO events(title,start, end, trainer_id, formation_id) VALUES ('Départ B','2016-11-18 10:00:00','2016-11-18 11:00:00','13','1')` it worked 
I didn't know what happen here !!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `$dataSource->commit();` after calling save() function